# Firefox canvas not showing anything after removed and added

Tags: firefox, canvas

I have a problem with the `<canvas>` in Firefox. Second time I remove and add it with Javascript, nothing will be drawn. I've checked the code and it seems find, it's even working in Chromium and Opera without any problems. Does anyone recognize this? I don't know how to debug the canvas.

I wish I could provide a code snippet, but I haven't been able to reproduce the bug outside it's code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas is passive to changes that may affect the content. It doesn't keep track of these things.

The solution is to always update the content when a change occur such as in this case.

You can also tap into window.resize (Chrome for example may clear the canvas if you use the dialogs etc.) and there can be other unknown factors. So never assume canvas will contain what is drawn but always redraw everything in those cases.

Comment: So there's no way to programmaticaly inspect what's on the canvas (not in Firefox, it seems)?

Comment: @OlleHärstedt inspecting the canvas is a different thing. You can use the `context.getImageData(x, y, w, h)` for this (but be aware of CORS restrictions will apply for images). This works fine in all the major browsers incl. FF. But to be sure canvas is keeping the content there is only one safe way and that is update the canvas when actions dictates there is a risk of loosing the content.

Comment: OK, I found the bug, finally! After removed and added the new canvas, I still got the context from the OLD canvas. Why it worked in all browsers except Firefox is a riddle. I only wish `getContext("2d")` would return `null` in such cases...